# passing parameters between methods of *different* controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, request, rack

There are already threads on how to pass parameters between methods of the same controller.

But is there a way of passing parameters between methods of different controllers ?

Because sometimes you have for instance an article for which, when you call the #update action on it, you also wish at the same time to update the tags associated with it over the #update action of the TagsController.

The idiom would be something like to instantiate TagsController in ArticlesController#actions and then pass a new instance of Rack::Response with only a :tags part of the whole params-hash to it while doing `tags_controller_instance.send(:update)`.

You would have to send only special parts of the params-hash which the ArticlesController received because TagsController will have different StrongParameters!

I think it boils down to the question about how to create a Rack::Request that copies the Request of ArticlesController on one hand and how to pass to it not the whole params-hash but only meaningful parts of it.

Then it should be possible to ask for the updated taglist afterwards with `this.tags` in ArticlesController#update, right?

Thanks

Von Spotz

Answer (score 1):

> The idiom would be something like to instantiate TagsController in ArticlesController#actions and then pass a new instance of Rack::Response with only a :tags part of the whole params-hash to it while doing tags_controller_instance.send(:update).

Please don't do that! It will be hard to understand & maintain. There might be other side effects you haven't even thought about too.

The question is, what does the `TagsController#update` do that you don't want to replicate in the `ArticlesController`? If it's some complex logic, I think you should abstract this e.g. in a [(service) object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) and call it instead.

Something like this:

```rb
class UpdateTags
  def self.run(params)
    new(params).run
  end

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def run
    # copy logic from TagsController
  end
end
```

and then you can use / reuse this service in your controllers

```rb
class TagsController
  def update
    UpdateTags.run(params)
  end
end

class ArticlesController
  def update
    # update Article or move this in a dedicated service too
    UpdateTags.run(params)
  end
end
```

Another approach could be to let `Article` accept attributes for `Tags` with [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

### Edit

To elaborate a little bit why instantiating another controller is not a good idea.

- What about before filters? Is it fine to execute them (again)?
- What about view rendering? You obviously don't want to render views so that's additional work and might have side effects?
- Other side effects like caching, logging, data analysis.
- Instantiating a controller is not a public API so this can change between Rails versions making an update difficult.
- It's not a common pattern so it will be hard to understand

I would just stress again that this is not a good idea to do. Duplicated code is better than the wrong abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for your hint to the service-object-idiom but I think this isn't really DRY. Updating changed tags on another controllers object is exactly a task controllers are made for.

Maybe the service-object idiom has it's own domain of problems but i don't think this is the case here.

Think of it as "Controller as service object". :)

Comment: "Another approach could be to let Article accept attributes for Tags with nested attributes." Yes, this is what I am doing now and I am very unhappy with it. I let the ArticlesController do the work that is actually the TagsController's work !

Comment: I don't think it is a particular bad thing to update tags in the `ArticlesController`? Obviously these two things are related somehow. I think your problem is more that your `ArticlesController` is not named correctly and you're missing some abstraction. What concept is an `Article` with `Tags`? Maybe it's something like `InventoriesController`?

Comment: But again, calling a controller from another controller is a very very bad idea. There will be other side effects (what about before filters, rendering of views) you haven't thought about. It's also not an idiom which is used in the Rails community or the intention of the Rails framework so it will be hard to maintain and understand.

Comment: I added some more thoughts about why instantiating. controller might be a bad idea in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This just sounds like a crazy [Wile E. Coyote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_the_Road_Runner) solution to a problem that's trivial to solve with [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

The only public methods of a controller in Rails should be the *actions* of the controller which are the methods that respond to HTTP requests and these *should only be called though http calls*.

Any other method [*should be private/protected*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions). There is no valid scenario where you would be calling `TagsController#update` off another controller to update tags as that method [*should do only one thing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) - update tags in response to `PATCH /tags/:id`.

If you want to update an article and its tags in one single request use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags`:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attibutes_for :tags
end
```

That creates a `tags_attributes=` setter that you can use update the nested records together with the parent.

And if you want to share functionality between classes where classical inheritance is not suitable use horizontal inheritance. In Ruby this means modules:

```
module Taggable
  private 
  def tag_attributes
    [:foo, :bar, :baz]
  end
end
```

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  include Taggable
  # PATCH /tags/:id
  def update
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    if @tag.update(tag_params)
      redirect_to @tag, success: 'Tag updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def tag_params
    params.require(:tag).permit(*tag_attibutes)
  end
end
```

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  include Taggable
  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article, success: 'Article updated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, tags_attributes: tag_attibutes)
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @article) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :tags do |tag| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= tag.label :foo %>
    <%= tag.text_field :foo %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  
  <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In some cases you might choose to use AJAX instead to create/update/delete a nested resource "on-the-fly" by sending asynchronous HTTP requests which do call another controller (but not in the same request). However this is really out of scope for this question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update an article and its tags in one single request" ? Do you mean that the actual `TagsContrller#update` method is called as well as the `#update` method of `ArticlesController` ? Or does accepts_nested_attibutes_for :tags just update attributes of some `Tag` instance ?

Comment: The later. The whole point is that another controllers methods are never called. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using params in many controllers, just add them to private methods in the application controller.